# How to convert ArrayBuffer sent from websocket into a MediaStream, and then transmit it to webrtc server via peerConnection.addTrack?

Tags: javascript, websocket, webrtc, mediastream, audiocontext

**The problem:**

I have audio binary data, sent from websocket, in ArrayBuffer or Uint8Array format. Let's name it as `wsAudioData`.

I want to transmit this `wsAudioData` to my webrtc server, and I can acheive this by utilizing the `RTCPeerConnection.addTrack(track: MediaStreamTrack, ...streams: MediaStream[]): RTCRtpSender` api.

However, `addTrack` accepts a track and streams, which are `MediaStreamTrack` and `MediaStream[]`.
So I have to convert my `wsAudioData` into `MediaStream` first.

---

**Here's what I have tried:**

I tried `AudioContext` and `audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination`.

```js
this.audioContext = new AudioContext({ sampleRate: sampleRate });
this.mediaStreamDestination = this.audioContext.createMediaStreamDestination();
```

When receiving `wsAudioData`, I will try to play this audio data.

```js
const bufferSource = this.audioContext.createBufferSource();
const audioBuffer = convertUint8ArraysToFloat32Array(wsAudioData);
const buffer = this.audioContext.createBuffer(
        1,
        audioBuffer.length,
        this.audioContext.sampleRate,
      );
buffer.copyToChannel(audioBuffer, 0);
bufferSource.buffer = buffer;

// Connect sourceNode to MediaStreamDestinationNode
bufferSource.connect(this.mediaStreamDestination);
bufferSource.start();
```

When the websocket is on, I will connect mediaStreamDestination with my peerConnection:

```js
this.peerConnection.addTrack(
  this.mediaStreamDestination.stream.getAudioTracks()[0],
  this.mediaStreamDestination.stream,
);
```

---

**Issues for my solution above:**

- The conversion is CPU intensive, when running this code, I can feel my M2 mac is heating.
- When multiple `wsAudioData` sent from websocket, multiple audio may be played at the same time. (I can partly solve this by using a cache array, when the array's length keeps the same for like 500ms, I play all the audio data in the cache array)

**Is there any other way for converting the wsAudioData into a MediaStream seamlessly? Thanks for you reading.**

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind using a Chromium-only API you could use a `MediaStreamTrackGenerator` to create a `MediaStreamTrack` without using an `AudioContext`.

```js
const mediaStreamTrackGenerator = new MediaStreamTrackGenerator('audio');
```

That `mediaStreamTrackGenerator` can then be used like any other `MediaStreamTrack`. You can push data to it by using the `WritableStream`
exposed via its `writable` property.

It expects the data to be in the `AudioData` format defined by Web Codecs.